# Typeguarding an unknown nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeguards

I want to create a type guard for an error that I know is a nested object like this:

```
const myError = {
   status: 404,
   data: {
        foo: "bar"
       }
}
```

The error, if it exists will initially be determined as an unknown type by the library returning the error. I want to create a custom type guard that checks the error and converts its type to something more appropriate.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
type MyError = {
    status: number,
    data: {
        foo: string
        }
}

const myErrorTypeguard = (myError: unknown): myError is MyError => {
    return (typeof myError === 'object'
    && myError !== null
    && 'status' in myError
    && 'data' in myError
    && 'foo' in myError.data)
}
```

This results in an error from the typescript compiler prompting that:

`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'object'.`

What's the correct way to type guard this kind of an unknown nested object?

Comment: With type predicates, it's generally perfectly acceptable to use `any` as the input type rather than `unknown` (which [fixes the problem](https://tsplay.dev/w171Km)) (and/or even to use type assertions in the predicate implementation once you've checked their preconditions, etc.). Is there a specific reason you want to use `unknown` instead, or does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TS 4.9+**

TypeScript 4.9 offers better narrowing with `in`, as you can read in their [announcements here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator).

```
return (typeof myError === 'object'
    && myError !== null
    && 'status' in myError
    && 'data' in myError // myError is now of type object & Record<"data", unknown>
    // the icky part: TypeScript requires us to do this... which is understandable
    && typeof myError.data === "object" && myError.data !== null
    && 'foo' in myError.data) // so now this works
```

[Playground (using 4.9)](https://tsplay.dev/WKO8zW)

[Same playground with 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiAnRB7RUC8UDeBYAUFEVAM7ACGwAriQFxQB2VAtgEYSIA0BxUAJpXL08hXsQBmKFPTKIAlgwDmPMUQC+BDfgIBjFAzJRmCZGgAq4CIqrlEfTFAAUxpKkT0qDANYMUAdwYASnoXU3Q5ElgTN0wAPhwVIkQIakQGJ1BIFHEjaLRMDCwAchRWACsIHWAixKgAMjrc13yAQkLGKgAbTtqGqCKyShoiqAUmsN7GooEKEbHQt0moTIhs8bcAOhnyAqwAIlKKqr36xoW0LcEoNqwmbqWiyRQ59PPES4pAzSA)

---

**TS 4.8-**

Unfortunately there is no easy way around it. You should just do a cast, even if it's ugly:

```
return (typeof myError === 'object'
    && myError !== null
    && 'status' in myError
    && 'data' in myError
    && 'foo' in (myError as any).data) // or myError as { data: {} }...?
```

Maybe even using `any` instead of `unknown` as the parameter type:

```
const myErrorTypeguard = (myError: any): myError is MyError => {
//                        ~~~~~~~  ^^^
```

Comment: Nice to see that improvement to TypeScript.